# Encapsulating OpenGL functionality in C++ objects while using QOpenGLFunctions

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I've decided to integrate Qt into my OpenGL project. Up until now, I've used raw OpenGL calls to make textures, make framebuffers, draw things etc. The problem is that the OpenGL calls are hidden inside objects such as the texture object. For example, you would give the texture object a string path in its constructor, and then the object would automatically load that texture data from the file and create an OpenGL texture with it( Obviously using OpenGL functions to do so ). Thanks to QOpenGLFunctions being an object itself, I either have to restrict where these calls are made, or pass a reference to it to EVERY object in my project that makes an OpenGL function call.

This really isn't desirable. Is there anyway I can get around this? Should I rethink the design of my OpenGL objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options. I personally think that having the rendering code localized in a limited part of the software is generally desirable. Explicitly passing a `QOpenGLFunctions` object to the classes that need it allows you to make it clear which classes do rendering, and maintain some amount of control over it. Unless it gets too cumbersome in your specific architecture, that would probably be my first choice.

Another option is that you keep a reference to the `QOpenGLFunctions` object in a singleton, so everybody who needs it can get a hold of the instance. While the use of singletons can be argued (and I really don't want to start a religious debate about the goodness or evilness of singletons), that's a very practical solution. Or if you don't care about hiding what you're really doing, you can keep the reference in a global variable.

As far as I can tell from the Qt documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html), it's also perfectly legal to create multiple instances. It doesn't look like the instances contain any state. So you could create an instance when you construct any object that needs OpenGL rendering, and keep it in a member variable. There's a code fragment that shows how to create a new instance on that documentation page:

```
QOpenGLFunctions glFuncs(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());
```

You'll just have to be careful that the instances are created while the context is current.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Does QOpenGLFunctions need to be used at all? Is it recommended?

Comment: I share the feeling for passing the pointer to your functions to the classes that need it. However a singleton and glFuncs should only be called if you expect a support of openGL 2.X. If you have multiple context and want a support for openGL 4.X functionnalities, call `QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions<T>()` instead. In my case I prefer to pass the context to my classes in an init() function. That gives me more information and flexibility.

Comment: Using QOpenGLFunctions has two advantages. 1) The functions listed in the class are sure to be supported by the current context you use. Second you don't need to include the GL folders nor the libraries in your project. Just Qt.