# Correct usages of QOpenGLFunctions

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

I a currently working on using Qt5 gui module to access to OpenGL functions.
Then I discover `QOpenGLFunctions` which is useful because :

- It wraps OpenGL for Desktop and OpenGL ES, making sure I am using the OpenGL API in a 'portable' way.
- I Don't have to worry about including OpenGL headers, Qt does it for me.

Yet I have doubts about a correct way to use it.
Following lines only list the three ways I know about using this class.
My question is : Is there a good way to use `QOpenGLFunctions` ?

**Inheriting from `QOpenGLFunctions`**

Qt official documentation says 'inherit you class from `QOpenGLFunctions` and use glXXXX classes like before. But I don't like this way as :

- If my class was expected to inherit from an other class before, I have to make multi-inheritance. Something I am not kind of. Even when such cases are safe anyways, it's aestethics...
- Every glXXXX wrapping classes are non-const. I would force all methods using OpenGL to be non-const. That does not make a lot of sens. Yes `OpenGLFunctions` class can legitimately be non-const when I do `glClear(...)`, but why my method `DrawableShape::render(...)` would be ?

And about inherinting from `QOpenGLFunctions`. Its constructor may accept an argument : the current OpenGL context. This parameter seems very important to me, but no Qt documentation calls this constructor. Instead they let the compiler to choose the no-parameter constructor.

**Having `QOpenGLFunctions` as member**

An other idea should be to have an instance of `QOpenGLFunctions` as member of any class calling glXXXXX functions, or at least a reference to one instance, and call every OpenGL functions from this instance.

**Passing `QOpenGLFunctions` as parameter**

For each function using OpenGL, the caller send `QOpenGLFunctions`. This way :

```
void renderRectangle(QOpenGLFunctions& opengl) const;
```

But how could I be sure *this* function will need it and *this* one won't ? I mean the source code will get bigger by the time and I fear the risk of seeing every methods of the classes receiving this parameter...

Comment: There were a couple of similar questions recently. I'll leave it up to others to decide if this is close enough to be a duplicate. But the previous answers should be helpful in any case. Question 1:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796775/encapsulating-opengl-functionality-in-c-objects-while-using-qopenglfunctions/. Question 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841355/qopenglfunctions-not-const-correct/.

Comment: Actually, yes I saw both of these questions. But even if both answers are valuable, I couldn't say they bring a good anwser on "is there a good practice for that ?", they only answer a "can we do that ?" question :)

Comment: Regarding the inclusion of a context in the `QOpenGLFunction` constructor. That is important on some platforms (Windows/WGL) and not so much others (Linux/GLX). It all has to do with how function pointers are loaded on each specific platform. On Windows two contexts may belong to completely different GL implementations, so you should always ensure that function pointers are relative to a certain context if you use multiple contexts. GLX is different, in fact you can load function pointers in GLX without even having a context - they just will not do anything when called until you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the same principle of other object oriented wrappers libraries you might consider a small variation of your third options.

Define a class representing your current opengl context that also extends QOpenGLFunctions

```
class GL : public QOpenGLFunctions{

  QGLContext& context;

  GL(QGLContext& c) : glContext(c){ ... }

};
```

The rendering thread will initialize an instance of GL providing its current context and pass it to all rendering instances that need to perform opengl operations. In this way you are also sure that you are not mixing multiple contexts when initializing and using opengl structures and buffers.

```
class Visualizer{

 void glInit(GL& gl){ ... } 

 void glPaintOpaque(GL& gl){ ... } 

 void glPaintTranslucent(GL& gl){ ... } 

};
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. Actually glXXX functions are not all wrapped in ```QOpenGLFunctions``` which forces me to use ```gl.doSomething()``` and ```glDoSomethingElse()``` at the same time but it is not really a problem. Thanks for the anwser.